# Azure Data Factory - MS Access as Source Database - Error

Tags: ms-access, parquet, azure-data-factory

My source is 'Access Database'

Dynamically generating Source query as '`Select * from <tableName>`'

But I got field names with spaces in source table, and destination is of type .parquet, Data Factory pipeline is failing with below error

**Example** if Table `Employee` got a column `'First Name'`

```
 {
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorJavaInvocationException,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error occurred when invoking java,
     message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:field ended by ';': expected ';' but got 'Area' at line 0: message adms_schema { optional binary RAM Area\ntotal entry:10\r
     \norg.apache.parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.check(MessageTypeParser.java:215)\r\norg.apache.parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addPrimitiveType(MessageTypeParser.java:188)\r
     \norg.apache.parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addType(MessageTypeParser.java:112)\r\norg.apache.parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.addGroupTypeFields(MessageTypeParser.java:100)\r
     \norg.apache.parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parse(MessageTypeParser.java:93)\r\norg.apache.parquet.schema.MessageTypeParser.parseMessageType(MessageTypeParser.java:83)\r
     \ncom.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetWriterBuilderBridge.getSchema(ParquetWriterBuilderBridge.java:187)\r\ncom.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetWriterBuilderBridge.build
     (ParquetWriterBuilderBridge.java:159)\r\ncom.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetWriterBridge.open(ParquetWriterBridge.java:13)\r
     \ncom.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetFileBridge.createWriter(ParquetFileBridge.java:27)\r
     \n,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.JniExt.JavaBridgeException,Message=,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.HiveOrcBridge,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Table Data to Sink",
    "details": []
 }
```

if i change query to `SELECT [First Name] as FirstName from Employee`, it works fine.

As am generating query dynamically, i was using '`*`'

Is there some setting on `Sink` (`.parquet`) to ignore `spaces` in column names?

**EDIT** some info here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4521, not sure how to deal in ADF.

And this link: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/28320

Comment: For now sorted it out by having select query and column aliases.